# Spring 3+ Weblogic and JNDI issue

Tags: spring, weblogic, jndi

This is my second question here, hope someone will answer this time.
     I am using weblogic 10 and EJB 2 but now I am to creating a new module in Spring 3.

Everything is working fine but I am not able use the existing datasource object provided by JNDI in spring context xml ....

Here are the files

Weblogic config.xml

```
<jdbc-system-resource>
    <name>EOrderDataSource</name>
    <target>adeccoClubServer</target>
    <descriptor-file-name>jdbc/EOrderDataSource-jdbc.xml</descriptor-file-name>
  </jdbc-system-resource>
  <jdbc-system-resource>
```

EOrderDataSource-jdbc.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jdbc-data-source xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90" xmlns:sec="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90/security" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:wls="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90/security/wls" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/920 http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/920.xsd">
  <name>EOrderDataSource</name>
  <jdbc-driver-params>
    <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@dicmdb01:1512:o2ks1</url>
    <driver-name>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-name>
    <properties>
      <property>
        <name>user</name>
        <value>asd</value>
      </property>
    </properties>
    <password-encrypted>asd</password-encrypted>
  </jdbc-driver-params>
  <jdbc-connection-pool-params>
    <initial-capacity>2</initial-capacity>
    <max-capacity>2</max-capacity>
    <capacity-increment>2</capacity-increment>
    <test-frequency-seconds>7200</test-frequency-seconds>
    <test-connections-on-reserve>true</test-connections-on-reserve>
    <test-table-name>DUAL</test-table-name>
  </jdbc-connection-pool-params>
  <jdbc-data-source-params>
    <jndi-name>EOrderDataSource</jndi-name>
    <global-transactions-protocol>EmulateTwoPhaseCommit</global-transactions-protocol>
  </jdbc-data-source-params>
</jdbc-data-source>
```

And my dispatcher servlet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:annotation-config />   

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.adecco.spring" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="weboDataSource" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

</beans>
```

Dispatcher Servet with Manual connection, which works fine

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:annotation-config />   

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.adecco.spring" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@dicmdb01:1512:o2kd1" />
        <property name="username" value="abcd" />
        <property name="password" value="xyz" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Even on the Java side its very simple to get the datasource object and its working fine:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext ();

DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup ("EOrderDataSource");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `jndi-name="weboDataSource"` in your spring config and `<jndi-name>EOrderDataSource</jndi-name>` in your WebLogic config. These names don't match.

Comment: Sorry my bad - it was a typo, spring config is using - EOrderDataSource

Comment: Please help!!!! Currently my weblogic have 2 JDBC datasource having JNDI name - EOrderDataSource and weboDataSource...I am using EorderDataSource.

Comment: Try using the resource-ref="true" attribute in the jndi-lookup element.

Comment: Code: <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="EOrderDataSource" resource-ref="true" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />     Still the same, on starting weblogic I get the following error        Could not autowire method: public void com.adecco.spring.data.SpOfficeDAO.setDataSource(javax.sql.DataSource); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}

Comment: You can also try lookup-on-startup="true"

Comment: I tried - still no result,still the same error.... do i have to add the <jee:environment>.

Comment: Well either the JNDI lookup is failing or you have a configuration problem. Create a minimal spring config first with only the jndi-lookup element and and say one class with an autowired DataSource and see what happens then.